# R shiny arrangment of horizontal checkboxes

Tags: r, shiny

I am new to shiny applications and I cannot figure out how to arrange some of the aspects of it. I currently have the following shiny code (along with the image of the output)

```
library(shiny)
channels <- c("social","digital","twitter")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("List Elements"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 2,
      tableOutput("listTable")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      checkboxGroupInput(inputId="test", label="Test", choices=1:4, inline = TRUE)
    )
  )
))

# server.R

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$listTable <- renderTable({
    channels  })

})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image: Original Output]

I would like to have multiple lines of check boxes for each word that appears on the left hand side which can vary in number. However I cannot figure out how to do so, I only know how to hard code in a certain number of lines.

Eg For the example above I would like the output to be:

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: Should one column contain all four checkboxes (per row) or separate columns per checkbox? While this can be done with a number of table outputs, there even seems to be a dedicated package **shinydust** for your task (no own experience with it though): https://rdrr.io/github/nutterb/shinydust/man/checkboxInputs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this could be achieved using lapply in combination with renderUI in ther server function and calling UIOutput in the Ui function. See example below:

```
library(shiny)
channels <- c("social","digital","twitter")

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("List Elements"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      width = 2,
      tableOutput("listTable")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      uiOutput("CheckBox")
     
    )
  )
))

# server.R

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  output$listTable <- renderTable({
    channels  })

  output$CheckBox <- renderUI({
    lapply(seq_along(channels), function(i) {
        checkboxGroupInput(inputId=paste0("test",i), label=channels[i],choices=1:4, inline = TRUE)
    })
  })
})


shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Although not aligned quite perfectly the naming system on the left you implemented them above each check box which would still work for my purposes. Thanks so much!